# Using get_wchan()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a question regarding linux kernel.
What header should I use in module, for using get_wchan() function?
I tried to find, but seems that all protypes are arch sensitive. Does linux 2.6.32 provides non-arch sensitive prototype of get_wchan()?

Answer (score 0):

Linux provides non-arch sensitive prototype of get_wchan(). For use it, should include asm/processor.h header.
But it can be use directly from kernel (not from kernel module), because symbol get_wchan not exported by kernel for modules (I mean EXPORT_SYMBOL).